# Xlookup not working with cell reference as lookup criteria, any fixes?

Tags: excel, xlookup

I have 2 worksheets within the same workbook(Sheet1 & Master). My master sheet has all the relevant data and is where i'm referencing for most my formulas in Sheet1.

[image: Screenshot of code working and not working]

As you can see from the images the formula in G3 doesn't work when using L2 as the lookup value, but does when you enter the value contained within the cell.

I unfortunately need it to work on the cell reference as the contents will be ever changing, any ideas?

This is the formula i am using for the Xlookup:
=XLOOKUP(L2,'#Master'!F:F,'#Master'!C:C)

If you need any more information, please ask.

Thanks,

Kind regards,
Ben

Comment: By default it's trying to get exact matches. Are you sure the value in L2 is clean numeric data?

Comment: I would test using index() and match() just to see.

Comment: I also realized maybe you are not showing all decimals in your numeric data.

Comment: @JvdV, I want an exact match. The only data that would be in the cell is 17.2, this is the full numeric data within the cell. What do you mean by is it clean?

Comment: @Ben, I was wondering if `L12` holds invisible characters that would throw an exact match off, thus no match.

Comment: @JvdV, in that case, it should be clean. The only thing I can think is that L2 is a formula that calculates the 17.2 value, It's a vlookup formula. Other than that I'm at a loss.

Comment: Right, so the result of the formula is simply not exactly 17.2.... add more decimals and you'll see.